# Regex - Get the content between two % chars without any matches which contains space

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get content between two `%` chars that does not contain a space.

This is what I have so far: `(?<=\%)(.*?)(?=\%)`

I think I need to use `\S` somewhere. Still I can't figure out how to use it.
There are always two cases:

1. I still get all of them, even the ones with space chars
2. I can't find any matches

A string would look like that:

> The placeholder is called %Test%! Now you can use it with real placeholders. But if I use more %Test2% placeholders, it won't work anymore :/. %Test3% sucks cause of that!

Comment: How about `%(\w+)%`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly,then just `%(\w+)%` will do it for you

```
    String str = "The placeholder is called %Test%! Now you can use it with real placeholders. But if I use more %Test2% placeholders, it won't work anymore :/. %Test3% sucks cause of that!";
    String regex = "%(\\w+)%";//or %([^\s]+)% to fetch more special characters
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Output:

```
Test
Test2
Test3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(?<=%)[^%\s]+(?=%)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pGqB4Z/1). Or, if you prefer capturing:

```
%([^%\s]+)%
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/pGqB4Z/2).

The `[^%\s]+` part matches one or more chars that are neither `%` nor whitespace.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/UvkH5z):

```
String line  = "The placeholder is called %Test%! Now you can use it with real placeholders. But if I use more %Test2% placeholders, it won't work anymore :/. %Test3% sucks cause of that!";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("%([^%\\s]+)%");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
    res.add(m.group(1));
}
System.out.println(res); // => [Test, Test2, Test3]
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! So you check for a charpart between the % chars and the part in the middle has to start with a % and can't contain spaces because of the \s?

Comment: @RotePfote The `[^%\s]+` part matches one or more chars that are neither `%` nor whitespace (as `\s` matches whitespace).